# Fraction and Whole Number that are divisible and substitution

Tags: java, templates

I am setting a fraction problem sum template that goes like this:

```
Mark has  3 1/3 times as many apple as Jane. Jane has 42 apples. How many do they have altogether?


Template Possibility 1 - fraction first, then whole number

@name@1 has #name#1 #name#2/#mul#1 times as many @fruit@1 as @name@2. @name@2 has #name#3mul @fruit@1s. How many @fruit@1s do they have altogether?




Template Possibility 2 - whole number first , then fraction


Jane has 42 apples. Mark has  3 1/3 times as many apple as Jane.How many do they have altogether?

@name@1 has #name#1mul1 @fruit@1s. @name@2 has #name#2 #name#3/#mul#1 times as many @fruit@1 as @name@1. How many @fruit@1s do they have altogether?


Another possibility, there may be another pair : #name#2/#mul#1  #name#3mul1  #name#4/#mul#2  #name#5mul2
```

The one with # is  the number variables while the one with @ is the text variables.

For text variables and normal integer variables I can random the values and sub it in to the template.

I am having problem with the fraction (#name#2/#mul#1) and whole number (#name#3mul) where these two are related in a way that the  **#mul#1** which is the denominator must be able to divide the whole number **(#name#3mul)** whithout any remainders or decimals.

I have a method whereby on the check of word by word in sequence, if there is a first #mul#1 found, it will invoke a method and return 2 things, the whole number and the mul value itself.

Now I have a problem of getting this 2 values to substitute in the question template as the whole number may come first then the fraction.

Any one of you have ever experience this and have a better way for generating the fraction and whole number that are divisible ?

Any advice or hints are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

PS: I working with JAVA...

Comment: This is a math problem, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot substitute in the numbers field for field for all of the cases you want to use, then you have to do calculations to make them conform.

This means formatting your input to the template so that what comes out is semantically and syntactically correct.  I'd probably calculate everything I'd want beforehand and do it this way:

- People involved (PersonA = "Mark" and PersonB = "Jane")
- What they have (What = "apples")
- How many Person B has (PersonBsAmount = "42")
- How many times Person B's does Person A have (MultiplyPersonBsByThisToGetPersonAsAmount = "3 1/3")
- How many Person A has (PersonBsAmount = "140")
- How many they have together (TotalAmount = "182")
- etc. etc.

Comment: So u meant is that all the numbers are random first and all the sets are divisible and correct?

Comment: Format the values before putting them into the template.  Don't try to calculate *in* the template.  If you need to simplify a fraction, do it before you send it to the template, and send it as a single value like "3 1/3".